# recalculate transform-origin on scaled element

Tags: javascript, css, transform

I have an element which I can scale and move using CSS3 transformations.
My aim is, to do the scaling always at the mouse position, so I set the transform-origin of the element to the relative mouse position of the element.
Zooming in and out from scale 1 works fine, but when I move the cursor over the scaled element, setting the transform-origin also moves the element.

I guess I have to calculate something like a "zoomed transform-origin" but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your desired effect, but have you tried to use `translate` instead of `transform-origin` to move the enlarged image according to the mouse position?